# How refer to a lifetime of a struct that takes no lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to implement an iterator for a 2D board. This `Board` is of the type `[[Option<u8>; SIZE]; SIZE]` and I created an iterator for traversing a square of given length.

```
struct SquareIterator<'a> {
    board: &'a Board,
    sqr_size: usize,
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
    row_iter: usize,
    col_iter: usize,
}
```

For convenience I figured I could implement the `IntoIterator` on `Board` to traverse the whole board aka a `SquareIterator` of `sqr_size = SIZE` and `row=col=0`.

So first tried this:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for Board<'a> {
    type IntoIter = SquareIterator<'a>;
    type Item = <SquareIterator<'a> as Iterator>::Item;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter { /*(...)*/ }
}
```

not surprisingly it doesn't compile: `error[E0107]: struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied`. Board indeed takes no lifetime arguments.

But I somehow want to tie the lifetime of `SquareIterator` to whatever lifetime a `Board` has. I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're implementing `IntoIterator` for the wrong thing!
Since your `SquareIterator` takes a `&Board` you should implement for that instead:

```rust
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Board {
    type IntoIter = SquareIterator<'a>;
    type Item = <SquareIterator<'a> as Iterator>::Item;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter { /*(...)*/ }
}
```

usually you'd add a `iter` or similarly named method to the inherent `impl` block of `Board` as well:

```rust
impl Board {
    fn iter(&self) -> SquareIterator<'_> {
        self.into_iter()
    }
}
```